# jQuery Mobile onclick event doesn`t remove class ui-disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, onclick

Before I started coding with jQuery Mobile the function which I have used to remove the class "ui-disabled" has totally runned. But now it only gives me back the alert message...

HTML-Code:

```
<div  data-role="navbar" style="padding-bottom:50px;">
    <ul>
        <li> <a href="#" id="choice1" class="ui-disabled" data-role="button" data-icon="star" onclick="radio1()">Simple</a></li>            
    </ul>
</div>  

<a href="quiz.html" id="next" class="ui-disabled"  data-role="button"  onclick="next()">Send</a>
```

Java-Script:

```
function radio1 ()
 {
   alert("test");
   $('#next').removeClass('ui-disabled');
 }
```

I also know that it is better if I use  this code example but it also doesn`t work..

```
$("#choice1").click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
alert("heymr.");
});
```

I Hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: why do you pass argument schwierigkeit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have declared the function incorrectly, so it is not visible:

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ntk9v2je/1/

```
radio1 = function()
{
   alert("test");
   $('#next').removeClass('ui-disabled');
}
```

This declares radio1 as a function on the default scope (`window` in this case).

As for the `$("#auswahl1").click` example: It works just fine once you add in the `removeClass` call:

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ntk9v2je/2/

*For either problem , also make sure you have correctly included jQuery (before these code snippets).*

Comment: Thanks, but that was only a mistake by translating the german function name in to an english name .. So that`s not the problem why it isn`t working

Comment: Updated with JSFiddle of the other problem

Comment: Yes it works fine now thank you very much :) haven`t seen this before  radio=function() {}; .  Have a nice Day ! :)